# Where is the data stored in Apple Watch and how to access it?

Tags: swift4, watchkit, apple-watch, swift5, watchos-6

I'm using Watch Connectivity to communicate between my iPhone and Apple Watch. I'm using the transfer file function to transfer a URL to my Apple Watch. I'm using the sample app provided by Apple in their watch connectivity link, the console says that the URL has been delivered however I am unable to access it in the Apple Watch. I do not know where the file is located. How do I access this file and store it in a variable to display on my Apple Watch in a table?

Comment: Can you provide some of your code to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I solved it. When you receive a file you can store it in a directory that you can access later. Thanks though.